# how to remove duplicate data in google sheets by python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

when i import the data into google sheets it keeps showing the name even though it already exists, how can i automatically remove those duplicates by python code. thanks everyone. Is is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFuci.png)

```
nrows = len(sheet.col_values(1))
sheet.update_cell(nrows + 1, 1, name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to remove the duplicated rows from the following your sample Spreadsheet. This image is from your question.

  [image]
- From your showing script, you want to achieve this using gspread for python.
- You have already been able to get and put values to Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```py
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set the sheet name.
rng = "A2:C" # Please set the range you want to check.

# Retrieve values from the sheet.
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)  # or spreadsheet = client.open("### spreadsheet name ###")
worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
values = worksheet.get(rng)

# Removing duplicated rows.
res = []
obj = {}
for r in values:
    if r[0] not in obj:
        obj[r[0]] = r
        res.append(r)

# Clear range.
spreadsheet.values_clear("'" + sheetName + "'!" + rng)

# Put the values to the sheet.
worksheet.update("A2", res, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

- When this script is run, by checking the column "A", the values, that the duplicated values were removed, are put to the columns "A" to "C".
- If you want to use only the column "A", please modify `rng = "A2:C"` to `rng = "A2:A"`

#### Note:

- From your showing script, I use `rng = "A2:C"`. If your actual range is different, please modify it.

#### References:

- [get(range_name=None, **kwargs)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.3.2/api.html?highlight=worksheet%20get#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.get)
- [update(range_name, values=None, **kwargs)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.3.2/api.html?highlight=worksheet%20get#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.update)